# Batch polygon clip doesn't work [ArcGIS]

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, openstreetmap, clip, batch

I have an OSM layers of a region, but want to extract data only for city that I am interested in for further export in Illustrator:

[image]

AYCS, I've created a polygon which includes the territory that I am interested in. But when I try to create a batch clip, I input all layers in a window and ArcGIS gives me the message "Overlay not Polygon".

What solution could it be? Really want to work only with features of selected area, because ArcGIS loads all the other features from whole region.

UPD: That's how this batch clip looks like

[image]

Comment: Is your clip feature class 'Drisnya' or is it a graphic that you've added? How are you creating a batch clip?

Comment: Assuming you're right clicking on Clip in Analysis Tools | Extract : What are you using for the clip features? Perhaps upload an image of your completed Clip table.

Comment: @smiller  - added a screenshot of a batch clip

Comment: Guessing since I don't read that alphabet; You a) need to flip your input and clip features and b) need to assign an output value for each line.  Right now it's trying to clip your Rectangle Drisnya by each of the entries in your batch, and only the first item has an output. You should be trying to clip each of the entries by Drisnya (Clip Features) and each record should have an output. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/clip.htm